Filtering days in a minute dataframe (in R)
Learning R for around a month now and first post on here, so I'll try to be as specific and brief as possible, but please forgive me, if it's still too abstract and difficult to work with.
I have a minute dataframe (as 'ymd_hms') that tracks (let's say) steps per minute over a month for different people/IDs. Basically there are entries for every minute of every day in that month for every ID (ignoring missing or untracked data for simplicity). Looks something like this (steps are either a random value x or 0):



ID
Time
Steps




A
2020-04-01 00:00:00
...


A
2020-04-01 00:01:00
…


A
2020-04-01 00:02:00
…


A
...
…


A
2020-04-30 23:59:00
…


B
2020-04-01 00:00:00
…


B
2020-04-01 00:01:00
…


B
2020-04-01 00:02:00
…


B
...
…


B
2020-04-30 23:59:00
…


...
...
…



(the real data has 1,434,540 rows)
Now, I want to filter out every day, where the total/sum of steps is 0 from this dataframe. I want to retain the original minute dataframe, but remove all the rows for all days where the summed steps equal 0. Simply filtering out every row that's 0 is therefore not an option.
What I am able to do is to create a daily dataframe that filters out every day in question.
Steps_df %>% 
  group_by(ID, as.Date(Time)) %>% 
  summarise(sum(Steps)) %>% 
  filter(`sum(Steps)`!=0)

However, like I said before, I instead want to retain the minute dataframe as seen above and remove everything from there (meaning every entry for the days where the total of Steps is 0; usually that should be 1440 rows, as long as there are no missing minute entries).
Obviously, if I changed the code chunk above to '...==0' I would get all the combinations of IDs and days I need to filter out every row for. The results I get would look something like this.



ID
as.Date(Time)
sum(Steps)




F
2020-04-12
0


F
2020-04-13
0


F
2020-04-14
0


M
2020-04-13
0


M
2020-04-22
0


...
...
0



(around 170 rows in reality)
The only solution I could come up with is to basically filter out each of these 170 combinations manually like this:
Steps_df <- Steps_df %>%
  filter(!(Id=="F" & grepl("2020-04-12", Time)))

That does remove all rows for that combination of ID and day, but since it is around 170 of these combinations, that really isn't much of an option.
Is there any method to do this in a more efficient way?
Either by filtering days in the minute dataframe or by applying the last code chunk to all combinations without having to type 170 of these?
I've searched online for hours and haven't found anything that would help me.

Your problem is that you are using summarize, which collapses everything down to 1-row-per-group. You can use mutate instead which keeps the same number of rows:
steps_df %>% 
  group_by(ID, as.Date(Time)) %>% 
  mutate(steps_per_day = sum(Steps)) %>% 
  filter(steps_per_day != 0)

But you can also skip the mutate and do the sum calculation in filter:
steps_df %>% 
  group_by(ID, as.Date(Time)) %>% 
  filter(sum(steps) != 0)


The above should solve your problem, but some advice on your attempts: if you ever find yourself in a position where you have to keep all rows of data frame A that don't match values in data frame, B, you don't need to manually filter each row--you can use anti_join.
Instead of your attempt
Steps_df <- Steps_df %>%
  filter(!(Id=="F" & grepl("2020-04-12", Time))) %>%
 ...

You could do this:
Steps_df <- Steps_df %>%
  mutate(day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
  anti_join(
    data_frame_with_all_the_zero_days, 
    by = c("ID", "day" = "as.Date(Time)")
  )

Lastly, I'd strongly encourage you to name columns intentionally rather than relying on the default names that get created from your code if you don't name them. It's annoying to have to use backticks for names with parentheses or other punctuation, and it will make your code more readable. Relatedly, it seems like day is an important part of your analysis--so add it as a column to your data!

Thank you so much Gregor! All of the three alternatives worked perfectly - exactly how I wanted them to. Beyond solving the problem your answer had some really valuable insights in general.
I had thought about a join before, but the “day“ column was the missing piece for me. You know there’s a way to do what you have in mind, but you just can’t put it into code yet, so that’s really interesting to see! Also, sorry for the column names. That’s what I’d usually do, but left out here. Anyway, I really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you!
